# How to ignore/redirect all URLs matching a certain string

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-status-code-301

I am using the Wordpress plugin, Timely All-in-One events calendar. Unfortunately it is creating a plethora of duplicate URLs which end in strings like (https://www.mywebsite.com/events/action~agenda/page_offset~-2/request_format~json/cat_ids~4) or (https://www.mywebsite.com/events/action~oneday/exact_date~2-4-2019/) for example.

As a consequence of these URL directives each being for a different calendar view but containing the same webpage title and content, some search engines are seeing this as duplicate content. Whilst robots.txt is setup to tell bots to ignore the URLs containing said strings, some crawlers are ignoring robots.txt. I have also disabled the various different calendar views so there is now only the agenda view but even in spite of this, bots continue to crawl these URLs.

Therefore is it possible to use Apache/ a .htaccess directive to tell the server to direct any requests containing "/action~" to either remove the string from the URL so the browser just reads "/events/" or to redirect/forward the URLs to another page.

There are over 500 of these URLs so I ideally would like a quick remedy!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrite in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events\/action(.*)$ /events/ [L,R=301]
```